# Checking the Solution of a First Order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please consider the following differential equation:
\begin{eqnarray*}
 (x + 2y - 4) dx + (-2x + 4y) dy &=& 0 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
I have solved the equation and my solution is:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\ln{( 4(y-1)^2) + (x-2)^2)} - 2 \arctan{ \Big( \frac{2y - 2}{x - 2} \Big) } &=& C \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Since this solution matches the answer in the back of the book, I believe it to be correct but I always like to check my answer so I take the answer and try to derive the original equation which should work if my answer is wrong.
\begin{eqnarray*}
 D\Big( \ln{( 4(y-1)^2) + (x-2)^2)} - 2 \arctan{ \Big( \frac{2y - 2}{x - 2} \Big) } \Big) &=& 0 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
 D\Big( \ln{( 4(y-1)^2) + (x-2)^2)} \Big) &=&
 \frac{8(y-1) \frac{dy}{dx} +2(x-2)}{4(y-1)^2 + (x-2)^2} \\
 D\Big(  \arctan{\Big(\frac{2y-2}{x-2}\Big)} \Big) &=&
 \frac{(x-2)(2 \frac{dy}{dx}) - (2y-2)} { (\frac{2y-2}{x-2})^2 + 1} \\
 D\Big(  \arctan{\Big(\frac{2y-2}{x-2}\Big)} \Big) &=&
 \frac{(x-2)(2 \frac{dy}{dx}) - (2y-2)} { 4(\frac{y-1}{x-2})^2 + 1} \\
 D\Big(  \arctan{\Big(\frac{2y-2}{x-2}\Big)} \Big) &=&
 \frac{(x-2)^3(2 \frac{dy}{dx}) - (2y-2)(x-2)^2} { 4(y-1)^2 + (x-2)^2} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
%
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \frac{ 8(y-1) \frac{dy}{dx} +2(x-2) - 2(x-2)^3 \frac{dy}{dx} + (2y-2)(x-2)^2}{4(y-1)^2 + (x-2)^2} &=& 0 \\
 8(y-1) \frac{dy}{dx} +2(x-2) - 2(x-2)^3 \frac{dy}{dx} + (2y-2)(x-2)^2 &=& 0 \\
 4(y-1)\frac{dy}{dx} + (x-2) - (x-2)^3 \frac{dy}{dx} + (y-1)(x-2)^2 &=& 0 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
At this point, I feel my solution is not going to check. Please tell me what I am missing?
Thanks
Bob

Comment: Divide the original DEQ by $dx$, then find the implicit derivative  $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ of $\ln{( 4(y-1)^2) + (x-2)^2)} - 2 \arctan \left( \dfrac{2y - 2}{x - 2} \right)  = C$,  giving $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{x+2 y-4}{2 (x-2 y)}$. Now substitute into $(x + 2y - 4) + (-2x + 4y) \dfrac{dy}{dx}  = 0$ and indeed $0 = 0$.

Comment: When I use implicit differentiation to differenitate $ln( 4(y-1)^2) + (x-2)^2)- 2 arctan( \Big( \frac{2y - 2}{x - 2)$ I do not get what you got. I get $\frac{ 8(y-1)\frac{dy}{dx} + 2(x-2) - 8(x-2)^3 \frac{dy}{dx} + 2(y-1)(x-2)^2 } {4(\frac{y-1}{x-2})^2 + 1}$. If you would like, I can post more detail on this.

Comment: @Moo, Yes, I mean the expression equals zero. So, I multiply both sides of the equation by $4 \frac{(y-1)}{x-2} + 1$ to clear the denominator. This gives: $8(y-1)\frac{dy}{dx} - 8(x-2)^3 \frac{dy}{dx} + 2(x-2) + 2y-2 = 0$. Am I on the right track? If so, how do I get rid of the $(x-2)^3$ term?

Comment: I have $$\dfrac{8 (y-1) \dfrac{dy}{dx}+2 (x-2)}{(x-2)^2+4 (y-1)^2}-\dfrac{2 \left(\frac{2 \dfrac{dy}{dx}}{x-2}-\dfrac{2 y-2}{(x-2)^2}\right)}{\dfrac{(2 y-2)^2}{(x-2)^2}+1}=0$$ This simplifies as $$\frac{2 \left(-2 (x-2 y) \frac{dy}{dx}+x+2 y-4\right)}{(x-4) x+4 (y-2) y+8}=0$$ Lastly, this simplifies as I show above.

Comment: @Moo, I get it now, thanks. Bob.